# What is a subpage in WordPress?

Tags: pages, hierarchical

Can someone explain what a subpage is in wordpress?  Does it look any different from a regular page?  What is its purpose and what does it do?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference between a page and a subpage is that a subpage contains it's parent in the URL, as will any pages that sit as children to the child page...

For illustration.

**Regular page:**
example.com/a-page/

**Subpage:**
example.com/a-page/a-child-page/

**Sub Subpage:**
example.com/a-page/a-child-page/another-child/

and so on...

Aside from the URL there's no other differences i can think of.

Answer (score 2):

Subpage is a page, but hierarchical depend from parent. When using automatically built menu will be arranged in this hierarchy.